# Export dynamic fields from Access to csv (schema.ini?)

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export a crosstab query from Access 2010 to a csv without a text qualifier.  I'm able to use the `Transfer Text` method with my other exports; the trick with this one is that the number of fields (and their names) change depending on what the user selects on the form, but the setup in the SpecificationName is static.  If I don't indicate a SpecificationName, I can get whatever fields are run in the query as appropriate, but I get quotes around my text fields, which I don't want.  If I set up a specification to set the text qualifier as None, I'm stuck with a set list of fields.  I tried sticking an asterisk in the FieldName area when setting up the specification, but got

> The number of fields in your export specification does not match the number in the table you have chosen to export.

I'd really like some kind of "SELECT *" in there, but it doesn't look like it's possible?

Poking around, it looks like I might need to set up a schema.ini?  Of course, this would need to be dynamic as well.  I found a resource that was written for Access 97: https://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;155512, but it doesn't seem to work in Access 2010.  Even after updating `db As Database` to `db As DAO.Database`, I get

> Expected variable or procedure, not module

When running the following in the Immediate window (with appropriate text subbed in):

```
?CreateSchemaFile(True,"C:\MyFilepath","ExportFileName.txt","qryCrosstabs")
```

I've reached the limits of my (limited) VBA chops to figure this out.  Writing a script for a dynamic schema.ini seems like overkill for just wanting to get rid of quotes, but if that's what has to happen, any pointers in the right direction would be excellent.

Thanks!

Comment: That error suggests you named the module *CreateSchemaFile*, the same as the procedure name.  In that case, rename the module to something else ... eg *modCreateSchemaFile* ... and that particular error should go away.  Unfortunately, after that I can't help you.

Comment: @HansUp - Tried that and got "Error#: 3265 Item not found in this collection."  After clicking OK on that, "False" appears in the Immediate window.  I don't see any new files in the specified directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, ok, I figured it out.  I thought I had to specify the columns in Schema.ini, but I was mistaken.  I just needed to set the header to true; that way it'll read whatever happens to end up in the query.  Setting the text delimiter to none was also a key piece.

Here's all I needed in Schema.ini (just needs to be in the same directory as the exported file):

```
[ExportFileName.txt]
Format=CSVDelimited
ColNameHeader=True
TextDelimiter="none"
```

And the code:

```
Private Sub cmdExport_Click()
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    dbs.Execute "SELECT * INTO [text;database=C:\filepath].[ExportFileName.txt] FROM qryCrosstabs"
```

While this ultimately works, having an external Schema.ini file is clunkier than I'd like.  I've seen a few places where adding extended properties to the dbs.Execute line will indicate csv (FMT=Delimited) and column headers (HDR=Yes).  Having one for text delimiters would be the most parsimonious solution, but from what I can tell, that doesn't exist.  I'm happy to be corrected on that if it does, though!